# Browser Compatibility Issues: Header displaced / Favicon missing

Tags: wordpress, header, cross-browser, favicon

I have two minor issues regarding my website [www.pitch-in.org.uk](http://www.pitch-in.org.uk) and the way it is displayed on certain browsers. One is regarding the placement of my 'header', and the other is my 'favicon'.

When using Safari everything is in the correct place, however when I open the website in Firefox the header is moved to the right and out-of-sync with the rest of the page.

Also, when I open the website using Chrome, my favicon does not show - but seems to work fine in Safari and Firefox.

If anyone could help with either of these issues it would be hugely appreciated!

My site was created using Wordpress, Pytheas theme. This is the first site I have created, therefore a little unsure of coding and apprehensive in meddling with the site's inner-workings.

Thanks for your time - I look forward to any answers you may have.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.pitch-in.org.uk/wp-content/themes/Pytheas/images/favicon.ico" />
```

is not placed on proper position inside your HTML document, it should be in `<head>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. Are you able to direct me as to where the tag should go?

Comment: Yes, it should be placed anywhere in between <head> and </head>, right after your <html> start tag.

Comment: * Thanks. Are you able to direct me as to where I should copy/paste this code? (where to find the head tag, and where to paste the code)

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much. The favicon now shows in Chrome!

Comment: Do you have any idea how to resolve the header movement issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code errors, such as the `X-UA-Compatible` meta tag; it needs to be in the `<head>` section and not where it is now. See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of   pitch-in.org.uk  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//www.pitch-in.org.uk/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code. Fix the errors and revalidate.